# ¿Cómo hago para mostrar varios autores en una tabla de libro? Siendo autor una tabla con clave foranea en libro

Tags: mysql

Aquí la descripción de mis tablas...

```
desc autores_libro;
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id_autores | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| id_libro   | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| id_autor   | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

desc autor;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id_autor     | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| nombre_autor | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

desc libro;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id_libro     | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| cantidad     | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| titulo       | varchar(500) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| id_editorial | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| año          | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| id_ciudad    | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| ISBN         | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| id_categoria | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Una idea de la consulta que quiero realizar es: `SELECT libro.titulo, CONCAT(autor.nombre_autor) AS autores FROM autores_libro INNER JOIN libro ON autores_libro.id_libro=libro.id_libro INNER JOIN autor ON autores_libro.id_autor=autor.id_autor;`

Esto es una idea de lo que quiero realizar...
[image: Resultado de consulta]

Lo que quiero hacer es que muestre el titulo del libro y todos los autores que lo componen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomando en cuenta que tu escenario es de *Muchos a Muchos*, deberías hacer lo siguiente

```
SELECT libro.id_libro, libro.titulo, GROUP_CONCAT(autor.nombre_autor) AS Autores
FROM libro
JOIN autores_libro ON libro.id_libro = autores_libro.id_libro
JOIN autor ON autor.id_autor = autores_libro.id_autor
GROUP BY libro.id_libro, libro.titulo;
```

**EXPLICACIÓN**

- Es decir seleccionas las columnas que deseas mostrar, indicando a que tabla pertenecen
- Haces el `FROM` de la tabla `libro`
- Haces el `JOIN` con la tabla que es `autores_libro` y los igualas en las llave primaria `id_libro` de libro con la llave foránea `id_libro` de la tabla autores_libro
- Haces el `JOIN` con la tabla `autor` en su llave primaria `id-autor` y la llave foránea `id_autor` de la tabla `autores_libro`
- Por ùltimo agrupas por la columna `titulo` de la tabla `libro`
- Deberás usar la función `GROUP-CONCAT` puesto que tu deseas concatenar los múltiples usuarios o autores que han participado en la creación de un libro

Enlaces de interés:

- [Ejemplo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=c07155b90f67096f8fedda696629c41f) funcional para que te sirva de guía
- Función **`GROUP_CONCAT`** de [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: Yo incluiría el `id_libro` dentro de la agrupación, solo por si hay dos libros con el mismo título.

Comment: Se podría utilizar cualquiera de las dos con el mismo resultado, pero por claridad yo usaría `libro.id_libro`.

Comment: @jachguate muy atinada observación, gracias

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo probaré.

Comment: Úsala y nos comentas @Edgar Fernando Alfaro Rico

Comment: Funcionó, muchas gracias.